# update a single field in the mysql while retaining the rest of the values in the other fields

Tags: php, mysql

Hi im trying to update a single field in the database and keep the rest of the values in the other fields but it keeps on deleting the rest of the fields.. not sure what im doing wrong? heres some code

```
    if(isset($_POST['submit_approve'])) {
    $comment = new Comment();
//  $comment->author = $author;

//  $comment->blog_id = $blog_id;

//  $comment->body = $body;

//  $comment->created =$created;

    $comment->visible = $_POST['visible'];
    $comment->id = $_GET['id'];
      if($comment->update()) {
      } else {

      }
    }
```

This is what im trying to update, as you can see i just want to update the visible field in the table and ive got 4 more fields commented so you can see..

here is the function

```
public function update() {
      global $database;

        $attributes = $this->sanitized_attributes();
        $attribute_pairs = array();
        foreach($attributes as $key => $value) {
          $attribute_pairs[] = "{$key}='{$value}'";
        }
        $sql = "UPDATE ".self::$table_name." SET ";
        $sql .= join(", ", $attribute_pairs);
        $sql .= " WHERE id=". $database->escape_value($this->id);
      $database->query($sql);
      return ($database->affected_rows() == 1) ? true : false;
    }
```

can anyone see where im going wrong? cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

most likely $value in your foreach loop is not set (false or null or '') for some items, but you are adding it to your $attribute_pairs array regardless.  Then in your updated you are joining it all up. Probably the easiest thing to do would be something like this:

```
if ( ($value != null) && ($value != false) && ($value != '') ) {
  $attribute_pairs[] = "{$key}='{$value}'";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to solve this:

1. Retrieve the original row, modify the appropriate field, and save/update.
2. Restrict the fields that get updated, probably via passing the fields to be updated as arguments to the method.